# How do I verify the file uploaded correctly to S3 with Perl Paws?

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, linode

I have uploaded a file to linode object storage (s3 compatible)

However, I need to make sure that the file uploaded is correct.

How do I verify the file uploaded using Paws or Net::Amazon::s3?
these are mostly mp3 files

EDIT
Im now getting "Forbidden" on ContentMD5 inside PutObject
its working fine when I remove that

this is my current code

```
use Data::Printer;
use Path::Tiny;
use Paws;

my $service    = 'S3';
my $region     = 'ap-south-1';
my $bucketname = 'KFC';

my $file = 'MP3/hello.mp3';
my $response;
my $body;

my $s3 = Paws->service($service, 
    region => $region,
    endpoint => 'http://ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com'
);

$response = uploadfile($file);
p $response;

sub uploadfile
{
    my $arg1 = $_[0];
    my $fh = path($file);
    my $body = $fh->slurp;
    my $md5 = $fh->digest("MD5");
    $md5 = "\"" . $md5 . "\""; # eq is not true if not for this >_<
    
    $response = $s3->PutObject(
        'Bucket'        => $bucketname,
        'ACL'           => "public-read",
        'ContentType'   => 'audio/mpeg',
        'Key'           => $arg1,
        'ContentMD5'    => $md5,
        'Body'          => $body
    );
    
    print "md5  = " . $md5 . "\n";
    print "Etag = " . $response->ETag . "\n";
    if ( $response->ETag eq $md5) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Can you guys tell me if this is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should compute and compare one or more following MD5, SHA256, SHA512 with sum at the source of upload. Read for more information -[How to Verify Checksum on Linux](https://itsfoss.com/checksum-tools-guide-linux/).

Comment: Doesn't the upload process provide feedback on whether it was successful or not?

Comment: @ikegami the PutObject method returns https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::S3::PutObjectOutput object

Comment: The docs for `PutObject` says "Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket."

Answer (score 2):

Include the `ContentMD5` header when you call `Paws::S3::PutObject`. See AWS's docs on [How can I check the integrity of an object uploaded to Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/).

Comment: Thanks!, I'm getting Forbidden on my current code, see the edited question. But it works fine when I don't include that, I just don't know if just comparing the MD5 of the file and ETag is fine or better.